# Post Creation Issue: 'postImg' Field Not Populated on Initial Page Load, Works After Creating Another Post Without Refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, react-hooks

"How can I ensure that the 'postImg' field is correctly populated with an image link when creating a post, even after refreshing the page? Currently, when the page is first loaded, the initial post does not have the 'postImg' field filled with the image link. However, if I create another post without refreshing, the 'postImg' field is correctly filled. The issue persists when refreshing the page.
The API for converting images to links appears to be functioning correctly, as it logs the link every time. Here is the relevant code:

> ```
> import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
> import state from "../../helpers/state";
> import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
> import axios from "axios";
> import toast from "react-hot-toast";
> import { useSnapshot } from "valtio";
> interface Post {
>   userId: string;
>   postMessage: string;
>   postImg?: string;
> }
> const CreatePost = () => {
>   const snap = useSnapshot(state);
>   const [img, setImg] = useState<Blob>();
>   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
>   const [post, setPost] = useState({
>     title: "",
>     postMessage: "",
>     userId: snap.userid,
>     postImg: "",
>   });
>
>   const navigate = useNavigate();
>   useEffect(() => {
>     state.logutBtn = false;
>     // if (state.isAuth) {
>     //   navigate("/login");
>     // }
>   }, []);
>
>   const handleImageChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
>     if (e.target.files) {
>       const imageFile = e.target.files[0];
>       setImg(imageFile); // Store the image file directly in the state variable
>     }
>   };
>
>   function addImg(link: string) {
>     setPost((prevPost) => ({
>       ...prevPost,
>       postImg: link,
>     }));
>   }
>
>   const createPost = async () => {
>     if (img) {
>       try {
>         setLoading(true);
>         const formData = new FormData();
>         formData.append("file", img);
>         const imageUploadResponse = await axios.post(
>           "http://localhost:3000/image/upload",
>           formData
>         );
>         const imageUrl = imageUploadResponse.data.url;
>         console.log(imageUrl);
>
>         // Set the image URL to user.profileImg
>         addImg(imageUrl);
>
>         console.log(post);
>
>         // Sending user data to "http://localhost:3000/api/create"
>
>         if (post.postImg.length !== 0) {
>           const response = await axios.post(
>             "http://localhost:3000/post/create",
>             post
>           );
>           console.log(response.data);
>           toast.success("Post Created");
>         } else {
>           toast.error("Please try again");
>         }
>
>         // navigate("/login");
>         setLoading(false);
>       } catch (error: any) {
>         console.error("Error:", error);
>         toast.error(error.response.data.message);
>       } finally {
>         setLoading(false);
>       }
>     } else {
>       console.log("Please select an image before uploading.");
>       toast.error("Please select the image");
>     }
>   };
>
>   return (
>     <div className="max-w-md  mt-8 p-6 bg-white rounded-md shadow-md">
>       <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Create Post</h2>
>       <input
>         type="text"
>         placeholder="Title"
>         className="w-full mb-4 p-2 border rounded-md"
>         onChange={(e) => setPost({ ...post, title: e.target.value })}
>       />
>       <input
>         type="text"
>         placeholder="Message"
>         className="w-full mb-4 p-2 border rounded-md"
>         onChange={(e) => setPost({ ...post, postMessage: e.target.value })}
>       />
>
>       {img && (
>         <img
>           src={URL.createObjectURL(img)}
>           alt="img"
>           className="w-1/2 mx-auto"
>         />
>       )}
>
>       <label htmlFor="img">
>         <img
>           className="w-10 m-2"
>           src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/458751/img-load-box.svg"
>           alt=""
>         />
>       </label>
>       <input
>         type="file"
>         id="img"
>         name="img"
>         className="mb-4 hidden"
>         onChange={handleImageChange}
>       />
>       <button
>         onClick={createPost}
>         className="w-full disabled:bg-red-500 disabled:text-black bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-600"
>         disabled={loading}
>       >
>         {loading ? "Creating Post..." : "Create Post"}
>       </button>
>     </div>
>   );
> };
>
> export default CreatePost;
> ```